# Python: How do I check if time exceeds a specified time?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm trying to program a car park charges calculator. There are various rates provided:
from 7 am to 10.30 pm - Rate $0.60 per 30 min
Night charge 10.30 pm to 7 am - Flat fee of $5

If the parking duration spills over from day time rates to night time rate, how do I calculate this? Below is where I am right now. I'm not sure where to go from here or if it's the right way to start.

```
def getCharge(self, endTime, startTime, rate):
    endTime = datetime.strptime(endTime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
    startTime = datetime.strptime(startTime, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
    # elapsedDays = (endTime - startTime).days
    # print(elapsedDays)
    duration = (endTime - startTime).total_seconds() / 60
    print(duration)
    blocks = math.ceil( duration / 30 )
    print(blocks)
    charge = blocks * rate
    return charge
```

To summarise:

1. How do I add in a check to if the parking duration exceeds 10.30 pm (where a flat night charge will be imposed)
2. How do I add in a check if the parking duration exceeds the night hours and into the the next morning after 7 am (day rate from previous day + night rate + day rate from next day)

Comment: Please provide fully working code to help us to help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Alex' answer, here's a slightly optimized and improved solution:

```
import datetime

HALFHOUR_RATE = 0.6
NIGHT_FEE = 5

def get_charge2(start_datetime, end_datetime):
    tmp_datetime = start_datetime
    charged = 0

    while tmp_datetime < end_datetime:
        if tmp_datetime.hour >= 7 and tmp_datetime.hour < 22 or (tmp_datetime.hour == 22 and tmp_datetime.minute < 30):
            # It is a day [7, 22:30)
            charged += HALFHOUR_RATE * 10 # avoid rounding error
            tmp_datetime += datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
        else:
            # It is a night [22:30, 7)
            charged += NIGHT_FEE * 10  # avoid rounding error
            tmp_datetime += datetime.timedelta(hours=8.5) # night == 8.5 hours
   
    return charged/10 # adjust result
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to iterate through every 30 minutes and count fees in that way.

```py
HALFHOUR_RATE = 0.6
NIGHT_FEE = 5


def get_charge(start_datetime, end_datetime):
    tmp_datetime = start_datetime
    charged = 0
    last_night_charged_day = None

    while tmp_datetime < end_datetime:
        if tmp_datetime.hour >= 22 or tmp_datetime.hour < 7:
            if tmp_datetime.hour == 22 and tmp_datetime.minute < 30:
                # Still not a night
                charged += HALFHOUR_RATE
            # It is a night
            else:
                day = tmp_datetime.day
                if tmp_datetime.hour < 7:
                    day -= 1
                if day != last_night_charged_day:
                    last_night_charged_day = day
                    # Charge one time night fee
                    charged += NIGHT_FEE
        else:
            # It is a day
            charged += HALFHOUR_RATE
        tmp_datetime += datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)

    return charged
```